# Android: как сделать неубиваемый сервис

Tags: android, android-service, background-task

Господа! Прошу помощи!

много примеров уже смотрел и никак не пойму: как же мне, все-таки, сделать на android сервис, который после закрытия фактического приложения - не умрет?
явный пример того что я хочу - яндекс.музыка. Качаете яндекс.музыку, запускаете, выбираете трек и слушаете. Потом выходите из приложения, открываете просмотр всех запущенных приложений и убиваете их все. а музыке хоть бы что!

вот какой я нашел пример и он все равно не работает

```
public class UnKilledService extends Service {

        final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onCreate");
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onDestroy");
        }

        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onStartCommand, FLAG: "+flags);
            //readFlags(flags);
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onTaskRemoved");
        }
    }
```

в фоне - работает. убиваю приложение - не работает.

Как это сделать? прошу, пожалуйста, помочь действительным советом, а не вопросами "да зачем? а там глядел? и т.д."

так же, хотелось бы не ответ типа [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

попадалась где-то тема, что в новых android версиях такой сервис будет иметь и обязательное уведомление в нотификациях - это даже хорошо, если найдется именно такой пример!

**спасибо всем ответившим.**

Comment: Попробуйте действительно с уведомлением сервис. Для этого в сервисе есть метод `startForeground()`

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению единого, точного рецепта здесь нет, к тому же это считается антипаттерном и именно поэтому начиная с версии 4.3 ось будет добавлять автоматическую нотификацию о запущенном "неубиваемом" сервисе.

Есть комплекс мероприятий, который в итоге (в зависимости от версии) может привести к успеху:

1. Декларировать `Service` в манифесте в поименованном процессе: `android:process="name"`
2. Пытаться запустить в `Service` не в фоне, то есть указать `startForeground()` - с недавних пор эта опция объявлена как `deprecated`
3. Запускать `Service` с флагом `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` - в этом случае при убивании приложения сервис будет поднят заново (если стартовал до этого)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте действительно с уведомлением сервис. Для этого в сервисе есть метод startForeground()

Добавьте и вызовите этот метод в сервисе:

```
private final static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 42;

private void runAsForeground(){
    //Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RecorderMainActivity.class);
    //PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            //notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentText(getString(R.string.isRecording))
                                //.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!
Решил вопрос путем добавления startForeground()
итог - именно тот, который мне был нужен!