# Http connection refused

Tags: android, сеть, http

Я сделал тестовую программу с сервисом STICKY и активностью.
В активности я стартую сервис. Сервис делает http запросы каждые 10 секунд.
Если не выходить из активности, все работает. Если выйти и запустить тяжелое приложение, то сервис работает недолго, успешно делая http запросы, потом убивается системой. После удаления тяжелого приложения сервис восстанавливается системой, но http запросы уже перестают работать.

Выдается ошибка на каждый запрос:

```
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to www.ya.ru/87.250.250.242 (port 80) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:238)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at home.xmpp.MyService.sendPostRequest(MyService.java:160)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at home.xmpp.MyService$MyTask.doInBackground(MyService.java:128)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at home.xmpp.MyService$MyTask.doInBackground(MyService.java:109)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
09-28 14:55:18.053 31161-31184/home.xmpp W/System.err:  ... 21 more
```

После возникновения этой ошибки, все последующие http запросы тоже выдают эту же ошибку. Помогает только перезапуск приложения. С чем это может быть связано?
Я пробовал делать http запросы в отдельном `IntentService`, который запускал в новом процессе, но толку нет.
Та же самая проблема и с `xmpp smack` библиотекой, вначале все работает хорошо, потом одновременно со сбоем http, перестает работать xmpp.
Что это может быть? Как решить эту проблему?

MyService.java

```
package home.xmpp;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentCallbacks2;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyService extends Service implements ComponentCallbacks2 {
private Boolean disconnectAppeared = false;
static MyService instance;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
MyTask mt;
Boolean mtruned = false;


public static MyService getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    return new LocalBinder<MyService>(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
    mHandler.postDelayed(timeUpdaterRunnable, 100);
    Log.e("MyService"," created");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
                          final int startId) {
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(final Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("MyService"," destroyed");
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(timeUpdaterRunnable);
}

public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    switch (level) {
        case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL: //Release any memory that your app doesn't need to run.
            //the system will begin killing background processes. !!!
            Log.e("Memory level","4");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private Runnable timeUpdaterRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (mtruned == false) {
            Log.e("Time", " update");
            mt = new MyTask();
            mt.execute();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        } else {
            cancelTask();
        }
    }
};

private void cancelTask() {
    if (mt == null) return;
    Log.d("MyService", "cancel result: " + mt.cancel(false));
}


    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mtruned = true;
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.e("http","updated");
            mtruned = false;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = "";
            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("data", "data");
                result = sendPostRequest("http://www.ya.ru", data);
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            mtruned = false;
        }
}

public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                              HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
    //Creating a URL
    URL url;

    //StringBuilder object to store the message retrieved from the server
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        //Initializing Url
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        //Creating an httmlurl connection
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //Configuring connection properties
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        //Creating an output stream
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

        //Writing parameters to the request
        //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String response;
            //Reading server response
            while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(response);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}


}
```

Update 04.10.2017 Проверил сниффером передачу пакетов после восстановления сервиса системой. На Андроид 4.1.2 все работает нормально, а на 5.1.1 раз в 10 секунд мелькает пакет SYN_SENT, т.е. запрос на открытие порта серверу. Ответ видать рубится системой, раз соединение не открывается. Это особенность версии 5.1.1? Если снова запустить активность, которая была убита системой, то соединение восстанавливается. Хотя сервис новый при этом не запускается. Что за глюк такой? )
Еще заметил, что на 5.1.1 возникает ошибка connection refused, даже если просто выйти из приложения и подождать пару минут. Система сама отрубает соединения сервиса, даже без его перезапуска.

Update 05.10.17 Попробовал на Андроид 6.0.1 эту же программу. На этой версии выдается другая ошибка java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /94.130.25.242 (port 80) after 10000ms
Возникает также после небольшого простоя, если вернуться в активность, то ошибка пропадает.
Снял видео как все происходит [Ссылка](https://youtu.be/v8f1eCmTDpk)

Update 06.10.2017 Как мне подсказали на хабре, эта проблема наблюдается только на Xiaomi c MIUI и решается только через okhttp. Если получится, то напишу решение.

Comment: Посмотрите в эту сторону https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628133/android-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81

Comment: Я все это проделывал, не помогает (foreground, broadcastreceiver,отдельный процесс). Да и не хочется постоянно занимать память, пусть система грохает сервис когда нужно, но лишь бы он после восстановления стабильно работал.

Comment: `Connection refused` обычно означает, что принимающая сторона (сервер) отвергает соединение. Сниффером посмотрите сетевой трафик, или еще как, найдите разницу в запросах.

Comment: А есть снифферы для Андроида?

Comment: В общем поснифферил я свой телефон, заметил такую вещь. Когда все нормально, то у http соединений статус либо Established, либо Wait_close. После сбоя http соединения в статусе syn_sent. Еще насторожила запись в логах при восстановлении сервиса системой    
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.644ms
Возможно в этом причина, система вместе с сервисом восстанавливает старые потоки, а у них уже тайм-аут? Возможно надо старые потоки очищать? Покопаюсь в этом направлении.

Comment: Похоже дело в параметрах ядра.. Завтра буду увеличивать согласно рекомендациям для нагруженных серверов: >>> net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 3 мой 60 !
>>> net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 30000 мой 1000 !
>>> net.core.somaxconn = 262144 мой 128 !
>>> net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 262144 мой 4096 !
>>> net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 262144   мой  128 !

Comment: Параметры ядра все расширил - не помогло!

Comment: Попробовал эту же программу на Андроид 4.1.2, там все работает нормально. А на 5.1.1 сбоит. Хотя WhatsApp работает нормально.

Comment: Хе, заметил прикол. Когда запускаешь активити после сбоя, он соединяется с сервисом и сниффер в этот момент показывает сотни открытых соединений и все работает. До запуска активити, только пара соединений. Похоже где-то здесь надо рыть..

Answer (score 0):

Добавте следующие разрешения в AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND"/>
```

И вот этот код в `onCreate()` вашего сервиса, это должно помочь.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            if (pm != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    String packageName = getPackageName();
                    if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK+PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE");
                pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK + PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "wetwars:activityrecognition").acquire();
                pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WetWars:WakeLockActivity").acquire();
            }
```