# Как объявлять переменные эффективно по памяти

Tags: android, память, android-service

Подскажите, какой способ эффективнее по памяти: иметь глобальные переменные и пользоваться ими, или в каждом блоке кода каждый раз объявлять их? Например, какой код будет более корректным в Android-приложении:

1.

```
private byte[] m = new byte[65536];
private int length;

void download(InputStream in) throws Throwable {
    while ((this.length = in.read(this.m)) >= 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

2.

```
void download(InputStream in) throws Throwable {
    byte[] m = new byte[65536];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(m)) >= 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Объясню, для чего спрашиваю. Система Android самостоятельно управляет запущенными компонентами Service и в любой момент по причине нехватки памяти может остановить его на неопределённое время, а затем вновь запустить его (благодаря флагу `START_STICKY`). Нужно не допустить перезагрузки Service, во что бы то не стало.

Comment: Это не глобальные переменные, а поля класса.

Comment: Почему вопрос выделен в списке?

Comment: Второй вариант правильней по код стайлу, если вы выносите переменное из метода то сразу у ревюеров к вам будет скоуп вопросов: где это ещё используется, брейкается ли этот while из вне, стучаться ли другие потоки, и все будут серфить чтоб узнать, если ли такое. Второй момент исключает ситуацию эту, и GC подчистит за вами когда загрузка закончится. Что касается второй части , это никак не влияет на работу Service, если в цикле только нет черной магии, типо отдельный процесс запускает тред и крутится, чекая жив ли ваш сервис и запуская сей в противном случае. Нужно было как ответ оформить)

Answer (score 2):

Второй способ эффективнее по памяти в большинстве случаев.

Переменные, объявленные в методе, живут ровно столько, сколько нужно. Поля класса живут не меньше, чем живёт сам класс (под словом "живёт" я понимаю наличие ссылок на него, т. е. что он НЕ может быть собран сборщиком мусора, но это НЕ означает, что он будет собран как только его "жизнь" закончится). Т. о. используя вместо локальных переменных поля класса, ты потенциально увеличиваешь время жизни содержимого этих переменных, а так же увеличиваешь размер самого класса.

Да и вообще, увеличивать область видимости (был метод, а стал класс) без необходимости - это плохой стиль программирования.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще глобальные переменные в Java - **дичайший моветон**, для этого есть синглтоны. В вашем же случае наследуйте Service-компонент и кладите в его поля состояние вашего сервиса.

По памяти оба ваших варианта *одинаково эффективны*, однако во втором случае требуются такты для выделения стека под ваши переменные при каждом вызове метода.

К слову, почему вам нужно, чтобы Service постоянно висел в памяти? Если так надо, то выставите ему высокий приоритет, тогда TaskManager андроида тысячу раз подумает, прежде чем закрывать.

Comment: В Java нет глобальных переменных.

Comment: как выставить высокий приоритет? в документации не могу ничего найти, в интернете мало чего.

Comment: @L'Esperanza, про неубиваемый сервис: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628147/11515